# NamedLikeFactoryMethod in Ninject Extensions Factory working in non-compliance with documentation

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a small issue with my simple example.

I have simple factory interface:

```
public interface ICameraFactory
{
  ICameraController GetNikonCamera();
  ICameraController GetCanonCamera();
}
```

I bind it as a factory:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<ICameraFactory>().ToFactory();
```

When i try to convert:

```
kernel.Bind<ICameraController>().To<NikonCameraController>()
.Named("NikonCamera");
```

to:

```
kernel.Bind<ICameraController>().To<NikonCameraController>()
.NamedLikeFactoryMethod<ICameraFactory>(f => f.GetNikonCamera());
```

it's don't compile.

For example, this code is compiled (but it's terrible):

```
kernel.Bind<ICameraController>()
.ToMethod<ICameraController>(c=>new NikonCameraController())
.NamedLikeFactoryMethod<ICameraController, ICameraFactory>(f => f.GetNikonCamera());
```

What am I doing wrong? 
`Ninject 3.0.1.10`
`Ninject.Extension.Factory 3.0.1.0`

Compile error: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21806986/Screenshots/shot_19072012_133454.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
this.kernel.Bind<ICameraController>()
           .To<NikonCameraController>()
           .NamedLikeFactoryMethod((ICameraFactory f) => f.GetNikonCamera());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I tried it and it didn't work. I have compile error like this: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/0/view/23e0vwi9fnjtx5b/Apps/CloudShot/shot_19072012_180915.png

Comment: But it's work:

    `kernel.Bind<ICameraController>().ToMethod<ICameraController>(x => new NikonCameraController()).NamedLikeFactoryMethod<ICameraController, ICameraFactory>(f => f.GetCanonEOSCamera());`

Where:

`public class NikonCameraController : ICameraController
{
//Some implementation
}`

Comment: Sry had it wrong in mind. The first generic argument is the implementation type (NikonCameraController) not the interface type. But there is a better syntax w/o this type. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer and for Extension.Factory! It's work fine. I think it can be added to the wiki (like best practices).